# Aws codebuild failed sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

Can anyone tell me that sometimes AWS Codebuild fails when developers push the code, but when I manually release the change, the AWS Codepipeline succeeds?

When i checked logs, the error is docker build -t "the repo name and the tag."

But yes, I released the change manually, and then there's no error and the codepipeline succeeded.

2 days ago, codebuild failed when I released the codepipeline manually. I tried 4 to 5 times; it failed in the build stage, then I released the codepipeline the next day, and the build succeeded.

Now, what was the reason that sometimes I failed and sometimes I succeeded? Please anyone can tell me that.

I thought that it must be related to AWS services in a specific region, i.e., Mumbai, and I checked with AWS health status, but all services are working in the Mumbai region.

I am using AWS code build environment managed image i.e., 5.0 , ubuntu , standard , latest version.

Also enabled privilege but i think it's not a problem because all the time codepipeline is working and in codebuild always that stage is succeeded but sometimes it's getting failed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).